# How to preserve focus on InputField after Print?

Tags: front-end, inputfield, eventhandler

If you press `Enter` in the example below it should become clear that test is being adding to the textbox instead of the current `Notebook`.

```
EventHandler[
 InputField["", String]
 , {"ReturnKeyDown" :> (
    SetSelectedNotebook[EvaluationNotebook[]];
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Notebook, All];
    NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], "test"]
    )}]
```

How might I force the text to be added to the `Notebook` instead of the other `InputField`?

**EDIT:** Ideally I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve removing focus from the `InputField`.

Comment: Does `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell];` inested of `..Notebook, All]` works like you want?

Comment: @Kuba Ideally I was looking for a solution that didn't involve removing focus from the `InputField`.  I will add that to the question.  But yes that does partially work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For version 9 or above, one can use `CellPrint` (or simply `Print`, as it is a specific case of `CellPrint`) which does not move the selection and thus preserves the focus on the `InputField`.

```
EventHandler[InputField["", String],
    {"ReturnKeyDown" :> CellPrint[Cell["test", "Output"]]}
]
```

---

Since the above code only works in v9, here is an equivalent with tedious selection-manipulation. First I set up the `EventHandler` as a cell, so that I can add a cell tag (`"input"`) to it. This is necessary to be able to navigate the selection back (`NotebookFind`) after using <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the `InputField`, as one doesn't know how many extra cells will be generated. Using `NotebookSelection` however can only get us before the `InputField`, but not inside. To move the caret inside, a specific `FrontEndToken` is used (`"MovePreviousPlaceHolder"`). Perhaps someone knows a shorter method.

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[
  EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic@test, String], {"ReturnKeyDown" :> (
      SelectionMove[nb, After, Notebook, AutoScroll -> False];
      NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[test, "Output"], AutoScroll -> False];
      NotebookFind[nb, "input", Previous, CellTags, AutoScroll -> False];
      SelectionMove[nb, Before, CellContents, AutoScroll -> False];
      FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`FrontEndToken[nb,
            "MovePreviousPlaceHolder", AutoScroll -> False];
      SelectionMove[nb, After, Characters, AutoScroll -> False];
      )}],
   "Output", CellTags -> {"input"}]]
```

Comment: The cell is printed to the messages window for me.  I'm on v8 what version of Mathematica are you on?

Comment: @Liam I was a bit afraid of this, as usually `Print` statements inside a dynamic gui controller get printed to the messages window, but for me, `CellPrint` here consistently prints to the actual notebook under v9.0.1. let me investigate this.

Comment: @Liam. the above code works fine for me using V.9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8

Comment: @IstvánZachar +1 and accepted.  Thank you for the solution for v8.  Both are appreciated ;)

Comment: Thanks @Liam, I hope it really helps :)